# How to parse through website HTML content

Tags: c#, html, parsing, browser, dom

I am trying to parse the HTML of a website, say CNN.com but everytime I navigate with a WebBrowser object, i get a bunch of null values for my object. I am NOT using the HTML Agility Pack. Whenever I call the Navigate method, mywebBrowser contains null and blank values. How do I get the tagCollection to populate? I tried doing the webClient.DownloadString just to get all the content of the HTML page, I can't use this because I will need to find all the tags and doing it manually is very messy. I also can NOT use the HTML Agility Pack.

```
        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            HtmlString = webClient.DownloadString(textBox1.Text);
        }

        WebBrowser mywebBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        Uri address = new Uri("http://www.cnn.com/");
        mywebBrowser.Navigate(address);

        //HtmlString does contain all the HTML from Page
        mywebBrowser.DocumentText = HtmlString; 
        //DocumentText only has "<HTML></HTML> after assignment


        HtmlDocument doc = mywebBrowser.Document;
        HtmlElementCollection tagCollection;
        tagCollection = doc.GetElementsByTagName("<div");
```

Comment: Why can't you use HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: @DGibbs I think that the OP was pretty clear on the cannot-use-HtmlAgilityPack front :) (the reason does not sound too important). Just, out of curiosity, perhaps it is because I use the WebBrowser for just very specific tasks, but I am not sure about the reason for using the HthmlAgilityPack. Can you please explain me what can the HtmlAgilityPack do that the WebBrowser cannot?

Comment: @varocarbas He certainly was clear. However, what isn't clear is **why** he can't use the library. If you need to parse HTML then it's perfect for the job and you better have a pretty good reason for not choosing it over other less successful methods...

Comment: @DGibbs I did understand your concern, that's why I wrote " (the reason does not sound too important).". You keep saying that it is better and my question is why it is better? I am not saying that it is not better, just asking for more information (if you can/want to provide it). I haven't ever had any problem to iterate through any html-element by relying on HtmlElementCollection of WebBrowser (as shown in the original code or in my answer) so I am not sure why HtmlAgilityPack is better (at least, on this aspect).

Comment: I want to avoid any licensing issues

Comment: @DGibbs I understand that you haven't -1ed my answer didn't you?

Comment: @DGibbs sorry (it was weird... but I wasn't expecting the upvoter himself...). Feel free to "continue this conversation" whenever you feel: I am honestly curious to get some insight into the HtmlAgilityPack benefits (so many people using/recommending it!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WebBrowser Class` allows you do many things without having to rely on any external library. What you are missing is the `DocumentCompleted Event`; it is part of the basic definition of the WebBrowser: before reaching this part the page is not completely loaded and thus the corresponding information is faulty (or null). Also bear in mind that in `GetElementsByTagName` you have just to input the name of the tag (without "<"). Sample code to show this:

```
 WebBrowser mywebBrowser;
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     mywebBrowser = new WebBrowser();
     mywebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(mywebBrowser_DocumentCompleted);

     Uri address = new Uri("http://www.cnn.com/");
     mywebBrowser.Navigate(address);
 }

 private void mywebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(Object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
    //Until this moment the page is not completely loaded
     HtmlDocument doc = mywebBrowser.Document;
     HtmlElementCollection tagCollection;
     tagCollection = doc.GetElementsByTagName("div");
 }
```

Comment: This worked although I found that I had to swap the order of when the handle was declared and the Navigate() was called

Comment: @fifamaniac04 I am not sure if I am following you: this code works fine on my computer and is OK (and thus should work on any computer). The DocumentCompleted event can be associated at any point (after mywebbrowser has been instantiated and before calling the .Navigate method). The exact order of the methods (DocumentedCompleted located before Form1_Load or after it) does not matter. Can you please ellaborate a bit more on the exact problem you had such that I can explain any unclear point?

Comment: idk, I uped it cause it lead me down the path to the solution. I realize that it should work on any copmputer, I just have mine swapped and it did make sense to me that we create the handle for the DocCompleted event after navigating to the page and then hit it afterwards. the sequence didn't make sense. I think your code should work excatly on any comp but it didn't on mine till I swapped the order. not sure if there was something i'm missing in some other file. but helpfull non the less

Comment: @fifamaniac04 I asked you for further information and you haven't explained anything: you don't need to change anything. Can you please show your new code? What you mean with swapping? I am creating a webBrowser from the Load event (and adding a DocumentCompleted event to it)... this is it, there is no order issue and I don't know what you are talking about. But, instead of -1ing me, you should have tried to explain your point (what I offered, by the way), to make sure that you understood everything properly. This is the point here: you ask to learn.

Comment: @fifamaniac04 also if you think that you found something so important which is missing in my solution and by bearing in mind that this is not between you and me but for anyone else with an equivalent problem. You should either tell me what is exactly wrong such I can correct my answer or post your own corrected answer for others (who might eventually vote you up if consider it right). But where comes the downvote into all this? Who are you helping with that?. Anyway...