# how do I use C# to dump a web page's HTML to a text file?

Tags: c#, html

I am working on a project where I need to be able to take a website url `www.google.com` for example and get the html for it in a text file to be parsed separately, but I don't know how to do so.

I know there is an easier way to do this than the way I'm doing it, but this is a project aimed at use and knowledge increase.

Comment: "*there is an easier way to do this than the way I'm doing it*" - what exactly you're doing? Can you show some of your efforts? Otherwise it is impossible to say - is there easier way or not.

Comment: So you're saying you want to get the contents of an web page and save it to a file? So in other words, you just want to download a URL? How else would you download something given a URL?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746627/how-to-parse-through-website-html-content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downloading just a single URL to a file is dead easy using `WebClient`:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(url, filename);
}
```

The trickier bit is that very few web pages really consist of a single piece of HTML - most then load Javascript, or load more data *with* Javascript, etc.

In .NET 4.5 and later you might want to use [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient) instead of `WebClient` - although it's asynchronous and (as far as I can see) doesn't provide anything *quite* as convenient as `DownloadFile` when that's all you want to do.

Comment: The current example does not work. Seems like you mixed up the two parts of your explanation and wrote `HttpClient` mistakenly in your example code instead of `WebClient`.

Answer (score 1):

C# WebClient class can help you to achieve this:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://somesite.com/default.html");
        File.WriteAllText(@"c:\YourLocalFolder\somefile.txt", htmlCode);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try  HtmlAgilityPack:

```
string Url = "http://something";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
string contents= doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
File.WriteAllText("X:\abc\def.txt", contents);
```

Comment: What library is that code using? And what's wrong with WebClient/HttpClient?

Comment: @JonSkeet I would say [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), pretty much looks [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400493/htmlagilitypack-htmlweb-load-returning-empty-document) ... :)

Comment: Right. So is this already parsing the html? If so, it may defeat the OP's intention (to parse later). It depends on the exact context, but this is a complicated way of just downloading HTML...

Answer (score 0):

If all else files, you can use the WebBrowser control to run IE within your application, this lets an jscript on the page run etc.   Then you can access the DOM from C#.